# Python Web Bot (urllib)

Tags: python, bots

I'm trying to create a simple web bot which will access a certain page, fill in and submit form data, and then print the page which it redirects to upon submission. However my resp.read() call keeps printing the initial form-submission page.

Here's the page and my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<P>Welcome <BR><P>Please answer the question <BR><P>98270+88340= ? 
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="vote.php">
    <input name="sum" type="text" id="sum" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="POST Answer">
    </form></body>
```

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import lxml.html as lh

#parse the operands
url='hidden'
parr=lh.parse(url).xpath('//p/text()')
elem=parr[2]
op1=int(elem[0:5])
op2=int(elem[6:11])
sum=op1+op2
print sum
sum=str(sum)

#request values                                                                 
values = {
"sum": sum,
"Submit": "POST Answer"
 }
 #encode for transmssion                                                         
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
resp=urllib2.urlopen(request)
#receive response                                                               
print resp.read()
resp.close()
```

I'm using lxml for the HTML parsing. It returns the correct sum.

Comment: Check out the [mechanize module](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), it makes this much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I got it working with mechanize

Comment: You should take this: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/801745a8-0bc0-4c9b-be05-595283e5be39/view-source  and make it an actual answer to your own question - don't edit out your question, it's useful for others to see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question resolved... here's the solution for anyone who'd like to see it.

```
import re
import mechanize
import lxml.html as lh

url='hidden'

parr=lh.parse(url).xpath('//p/text()')
elem=parr[2]
op1=int(elem[0:5])
op2=int(elem[6:11])
sum=op1+op2
print sum
sum=str(sum)

br=mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)

br.select_form(name="loginform")
br["sum"]=sum
resp=br.submit()

br.select_form(name="poll")
br["vote"]=["7"]
resp2=br.submit()

print resp2.read()
```

Basically the bot opens the url, parses the page for two operands, then inputs the sum into the form before proceeding to vote on a poll in the following page.